# Angular, Stop one chrome tab from reloading

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Angular, is there any way to stop only one chrome tab from reloading, just for comparison purposes ?

Comment: is not clear what do you need exactly

Comment: For instance, I want to compare two styles, like a layout or button, I need a tab with the old and another with the new one, but whenever I hit save both of the tabs reload

Comment: when you run your code every tab with the same port will be reloaded so the solution try to  run ng serve --port 4200 for the first , and in the same project run ng serve --port 4300 for example

Comment: What you could do is implement a before unload listener and ask for confirmation to reload the page. When you save, just hit `cancel` on one tab and let the other reload.

Comment: @MikeS. works like rookie on his first day of work, could you write that as an answer ?, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MikeS. method works like a charm, basically you need to run this in your browser tab 's developers tools console to prevent it from reloading :

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = '';
});
```

Comment: thanks ... I am getting a popup asking for reload, just chose no.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the project and run with different port like below.
`ng serve --port 4200`

That is better alternative.

There is no way to have tabs stopped reloading when served by angular.